# Good books on the theories behind UML/data modeling for web apps?

Tags: database-design, uml

Trying to better my grasp on this area of application design/architecture/development and looking for any suggestions in this area. I have read some other posts and have a list of development theory books, but would like to form a list for more architecture based books that relate to web based applications. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First thing that jumps to mind for me is Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture by Martin Fowler.

http://books.google.ca/books?id=FyWZt5DdvFkC&dq=patterns+of+enterprise+application+architecture&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=jr9XS6H-J4KY8Abs_eXJAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false

### Addendum

Damn! Poking around on Martin Fowler's Web Site I found "Refactoring HTML: Improving the Design of Existing Web Applications" in his signature series...

It looks quite interesting. Its material focuses on moving away from "tag soup, presentation-based markup and stateful applications" towards "XHTML, CSS and REST."

Haven't read it but it sure looks promising.

Comment: Thank you, I actually had just opened that page and was looking at it a few minutes ago. The subject seems interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I have the good old "Building Web Applications UML" in my bookshelf, but yeah it is only worth the 5 bucks for which you can order it from amazon.

[http://www.amazon.com/Building-Web-Applications-UML-2nd/dp/0201730383/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1264090325&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201730383)

Not that the book is bad but IMHO UML for web apps doesn't make really sense.

[image]